# error: rust 1.41.1 does't not match extension requirment, building wheel for bcrypt does'nt run successfuly

Tags: python, linux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JBJU.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khs8m.png)error: rust 1.41.1 do not match extension requirment,  building wheel for bcrypt does'nt run successfuly, everthing else is there in image. please help me.
i have updated the python3.8 and python3.9.5. i have also updated the rust version to the latest one still showing the same error. i don't understand what to do now. i have also tried pip updating and reflash image in server. i have used rasp. pi as my server.
thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The latest rust version for your RPi is apparently 1.41.1 and not 1.56 which is what is needed.  How did you install rust?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I installed Rust using the recommended way on its page, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just run myself into this same issue. However, for a different reason, it has the same origin:

- [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/)

Most likely the version of `bcrypt` you are trying to install, has a dependency over the above package. When installed automatically as a dependency it will generate that error as the latest version requires a higher version of Rust higher than the one installed by default with cargo.

In my case, this solved the problem:

```
pip3 install cryptography==3.3.1
```

I got this solution from this French forum - [LINK](https://community.jeedom.com/t/error-rust-1-41-1-does-not-match-extension-requirement-1-48-0/90270/2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error when installing netmiko on a Rassperberry PI4 running Debian 10. The only way to solve this problem was to download the tar.gz file from the Rust-lang website for my platform. The stable version is 1.7.1. First, I checked my architecture with uname -m. After that, I downloaded the version of the software for my architecture using wget. I unpacked the archive using tar xf . Then I ran sudo ./install.sh from the archive. If it does not run, you should grant access rights using chmod +x install.sh.
Version 1.7.1 met the requirements for installing netmiko and everything worked. The problem is solved.

Comment: Please answer OPs question with a solution that worked underlying the steps you took to get it resolved. It gets easy for others to read and follow what worked for you. Thanks for contributing.